# Map data structure which allows O(nr_entries * log(N)) traversal time

Tags: java, data-structures

Is there any map data structure in Java which allows me to iterate over the smallest k elements in less than O(N) time (where N is the size of the entire map, with k << N)?

Note: a `TreeMap` returns all keys smaller than a given value, but I need the first k keys. (taken from deleted answer that proposed to use a `TreeMap`).

Comment: why would you used a chainsaw when you can use a table knife to cut bread? What is your rationale behind saying map data structure? For what you want you can use a sorted linked list for instance.

Comment: Won't a common TreeMap allow you to iterate exactly with O(k) time?

Comment: That note makes no sense. Those _are_ the first k keys! You just need to get the ordering right: if the ordering needs to be "order of insertion", then wrap the objects in other objects which contain `insertionOrder` and compare the `insertionOrder` fields to implement `Comparable`. But that seems like kind of an overcomplicated solution to a simple problem.

Comment: @RobinGreen I guess OP wants/need the first k values, not keys.

Comment: Then he should say so.

Comment: @RobinGreen I agree that OP should work on giving a better explanation of the problem.

Comment: I have a system which generates a mapping from time stamps to events. This mapping is used in many places. It's just a mapping from a Long which represents time to an object called event. From time to time I need to remove the smallest event in terms of timestamp which hasn't yet been selected for processing. In other words I need to go through this mapping in order of timestamps and select the smallest event not yet marked for processing (this is on avg resolved within 3-4 iterations). A common iteration of TreeMap has you cast it to an entrySet which seems to be O(n).

Answer (score 1):

If by "smallest" you are referring to the order as determined by the `Comparable` interface on the members, then `TreeMap`.

Comment: From a deleted answer that covered this, OP commented: *That doesn't do what I need it to do because that returns all keys smaller than a given value, but I need the first k keys*.

Comment: A TreeMap requires you to cast it to an entrySet which seems to be O(n) time. I just wanted to iterate over the smallest elements (in terms of keys) and when a condition is met exit. Not convert the whole tree to an entry Set

Comment: Why do you think it is O(n) time? It's a view, so it should be O(1) time.